# Use of "do" together to another verb

Tags: word-usage

I have a doubt, is the use of "do" together to another verb correct?, And if it is what is the difference if I do not put "Do" and just the other verb.

Comment: What are you talking about?? What **do you mean** "together to [with] another verb"?? do/does is for questions and negative sentences in English. It's called a helping verb. You can ask a question properly or make a negative sentence without them...

Comment: For example I've read: "I do grown", is not the same to say " I grown"?

Comment: "I grown" is incorrect, it should be "I have grown" or "I grow".  "I do grown" is also incorrect.  "I do grow" is grammatically correct, but in standard English I do not think you would use it unless you particularly needed to emphasise the truth of the statement.  For example.  "You don't grow."  "I _do_ grow".

Comment: Those uses are regional and/or dialectical, for example, southern US or Black English (AmE).